# SQL Select until Quantity Met

Tags: sql

i need a sql query that can show something like this :

My Data :

```
| id | Purchase Number | Qty |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1 | A   | 3 |
| 2 | B   | 2 |
| 3 | C   | 4 |
```

For example i need to take 6 Qty
I want the result will be like this :

```
| id | Purchase Number | Qty |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 1 | A   | 3 |
| 2 | B   | 2 |
| 3 | C   | 1|
```

I've read similar thread but cant find what i need

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your question needs a bit more clarification. What do you mean by "taking 6 qty"? Why do you want the C row to show 1 in the Qty field?

Comment: Sorry , i use SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select id, purchase_number,
       (case when running_qty < 6 then qty
             else 6 - (running_qty - qty)
        end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(qty) over (order by id) as running_qty
      from t
     ) t
where running_qty - qty < 6;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=933e695eb0f55e6033ce438215bf1fa6) is a db<>fiddle (which uses Postgres but this is standard SQL).

Comment: can you help me with SQL Server 2008 Query ? I have an error near order

Comment: @AngelNova . . . This query will work in all supported versions of SQL Server.  Why are you using an unsupported version?

Comment: it doesnt work on SQL SERVER 2008 and under , but i found a way how to do it . Thank you