# How to implement a greedy SELECT of rows in a table until a cumulative grouped where condition is met

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am attempting to simulate a (normally non-SQL) scanner using SQL.

The scanner attempts to select rows from the table in a first come first serve basis while attempting to satisfy some constraints specific to the table columns.

I have a table which can be described by the schema below:

```
Tablename Table 

name STRING
time TIMESTAMP
identifier STRING
```

### Sample Input Table:

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sid | 2-28-2022 10:55 EST | identifier1 | 0 |
| Bob | 2-28-2022 10:50 EST | identifier2 | 1 |
| Sid | 2-28-2022 10:45 EST | identifier2 | 2 |
| Sid | 2-28-2022 10:35 EST | identifier2 | 3 |
| Bob | 2-28-2022 10:25 EST | identifier1 | 4 |

### Sample Constraints:

Hourly Frequency Cap = 2 (no more than 2 rows Per name Per hourly block),

Identifier1 Cap = 2 (no more than 2 rows total containing identifier 1),

Identifier2 Cap = 2 (no more than 2 rows total containing identifier 2)

### Expected Output Table:

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2-28-2022 10:25 EST | identifier 1 | 4 |
| Sid | 2-28-2022 10:35 EST | identifier 2 | 3 |
| Sid | 2-28-2022 10:45 EST | identifier 2 | 2 |

Observe that row_number 1 did not make the cut because we exceeded the Cap on identifier2 is 2, observe that row_number 0 did not make the cut because we exceeded the Hourly Frequency Cap for the name "Sid". The Cap on Identifier1 did not affect the data.

### Another Sample Input Table (larger):

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sid | 3-08-2022 12:01 EST | identifier2 | 0 |
| Sid | 3-08-2022 11:03 EST | identifier 2 | 1 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 11:02 EST | identifier 2 | 2 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 11:01 EST | identifier 2 | 3 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:28 EST | identifier2 | 4 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:27 EST | identifier2 | 5 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:26 EST | identifier3 | 6 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:25 EST | identifier1 | 7 |

### Constraints:

Hourly Frequency Cap = 2, so for a given name no more than 2 rows per hour

Identifier1 Publisher Cap = 2, No more than 2 rows containing identifier=Identifier1 in total for the resultant table

Identifier2 Publisher Cap = 2, No more than 2 rows containing identifier=Identifier2 in total for the resultant table

Identifier3 Publisher Cap = 2, No more than 2 rows containing identifier=Identifier3 in total for the resultant table

Omitting Daily Frequency cap to keep this example simple.

### Output Table:

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:25 EST | identifier1 | 7 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 10:26 EST | identifier3 | 6 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 11:01 EST | identifier 2 | 3 |
| Bob | 3-08-2022 11:02 EST | identifier 2 | 2 |

### Explanation:

Going in order of time, row 7 and row 6 slide in fine, Rows 5 and 4 get ignored because Bob has already been assigned two rows for the 10:00 hourly block, and is therefore at the limit for his Hourly cap.

Now at 11:00 the hourly cap gets reset, so rows 3 and 2 again make the cut. Now row 1 gets ignored because even though its a new name "Sid" the identifier "identifier2" has already saturated its publisher cap (2).

Now at 12:00 we again ignore row 0 because once again we recall the total publisher cap on "identifier2" has already been saturated.

### Third Example Table:

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:00:00 UTC | identifier1 | 1 |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:01:00 UTC | identifier1 | 2 |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:02:00 UTC | identifier2 | 3 |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:03:00 UTC | identifier2 | 4 |
| Bob | 2022-02-28 15:04:00 UTC | identifier2 | 5 |

Constraints: Hourly frequency cap (2) [no more than two requests per name per hour], identifier1 and identifier2 publisher cap (2) [no more than 2 requests for each identifier in total]

### Expected output table:

| name (string) | time (timestamp) | identifier (string) | row_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:00:00 UTC | identifier1 | 1 |
| Sid | 2022-02-28 15:01:00 UTC | identifier1 | 2 |
| Bob | 2022-02-28 15:04:00 UTC | identifier2 | 5 |

### Explanation:

The scanner picks up the first two rows, now it has saturated "Sid" for the hour so it cannot pick any further rows with name "Sid", but when the last row containing "Bob "comes along it CAN pick up additional rows for Bob, furthermore since the "Bob" row has "identifier2" we dont come up against the "identifier1" frequency cap either.

### Fourth Table Example:

Consider the table given by

```
WITH initial_table AS (
SELECT "sid" as name, timestamp("2022-03-08 07:25:00-08") as time1, "pub1" as identifier UNION ALL
SELECT "sid" as name, timestamp("2022-03-08 07:26:01-08") as time1, "pub1" as identifier UNION ALL 
SELECT "bob" as name, timestamp("2022-03-08 07:26:02-08") as time1, "pub1" as identifier UNION ALL  --this gets ignored because pub1 is saturated
SELECT "bob" as name, timestamp("2022-03-08 07:26:03-08") as time1, "pub1" as identifier UNION ALL  --this gets ignored too because pub1 is saturated 
SELECT "bob" as name, timestamp("2022-03-08 07:26:04-08") as time1, "pub2" as identifier   --this should not get ignored, pub2 hasn't hit its publisher cap

),
```

And suppose our identifier cap is (2) per identifier, and we have a frequency cap of (2) per hour for each name.

We can see that a greedy selection of rows in time order would pick up the first two rows containing name="Sid" and the very last row containing name="Bob", identifier="pub2" but not any of the others.

### Some links I reviewed:

[Select rows until condition met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232282/select-rows-until-condition-met)

This doesn't solve my problem because its not possible to determine the "condition" ending before runtime, and then use that index to stop the query. In this case the query's end time/end index can only be found at runtime and not during preprocessing.

[SQL Select until Quantity Met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65323364/sql-select-until-quantity-met)

This almost solves my problem but I can't again run a cumulative sum because I don't actually get to know which rows might be accepted/order of the rows.

[How to pull rows from a SQL table until quotas for multiple columns are met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70337674/how-to-pull-rows-from-a-sql-table-until-quotas-for-multiple-columns-are-met?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Also runs into the same trip up as the earlier problem: because we have this odd group by/frequency cap happening simultaneously.

### Some methodologies I considered:

1. [State] If can have a "state" in my query, that is a variable keeping track of how many of each identifier I have seen so far, then I could use a case statement to update this. Something along the lines of the following

`SELECT *, (CASE identifier = "identifier1" then SET identifier1counter = identifier1counter - 1)  WHERE (identifier="identifier1" AND identifier1counter > 0) ...`

But this ended up being nonsensical in the context of SQL

2. [Drop SQL] I could try to forget SQL and actually simulate the bidder using bigquery's scripting language. This actually works but is very slow since it instantiates 1 brand new query per row. So I think i'm trapped with SQL

Comment: Way too much text and filler in your question.  Just show us the sample data, the output you want from that data, along with whatever you may have tried already.

Comment: Changing it now

Answer (score 1):

For this I think you have to deal a lot with conditional and numbering expressions, also your filtering options are kind of restrictive and similar  to a `distinct` clause. Anyways I found a way to get it working. Let me discuss my think process:

I created a table named `table` on BigQuery I proceed to add your data

```
create table `project-id.dataset-id.table`(
  name STRING,
  time timestamp,
  identifier STRING,
  row_number INT64
)

/*
filling your table with data
insert into `project-id.dataset-id.table` (name,time,identifier,row_number)
values('Bob',timestamp('2022-02-28 xx:xx:00 EST'),'identifier1',4);
...
*/
```

Working with `with` and `row_number` to generate sql script:

```
with working_data as(
    select name,identifier,time,row_number,
        EXTRACT(HOUR from time) hour,
        row_number() over(order by time) id
    from `project-id.dataset-id.table` 
    order by id
), identifier_filter as (
   select id,identifier, row_number() over (partition by identifier,hour order by time) instances from working_data 
   order by time
), name_filter as (
  select id,name,row_number() over (partition by name,hour order by time) instances from working_data
  order by time
), clean as(
  select w.*,row_number() over(partition by w.identifier order by time) instances from working_data w
  left join name_filter x on x.id = w.id and x.instances <=2
  left join identifier_filter y on y.id = w.id and y.instances <=2 
  where x.name is not null and y.identifier is not null
  order by w.time
)
select * from clean
where instances <=2
```

**UPDATE 9/3/2022**: I have updated my code and it should work with both tests scenarios. I also added a bit of refinement so it basically plays alongside your filters, then we match both and then remove any leftover in the final select.

I revised the following documentation pages:

- [case](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#case)
- [row_number](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number)

Comment: im still parsing your answer but I want to comment that your observation that "select distinct" is just an "n=1" cap is really clever, i haven't thought of it that way

Comment: Hello @frogeyedpeas, have you managed to make it work?

Comment: unfortunately I can't get it working yet, the constraint for identifier capping needs to hold true over the entire set of returned rows (as opposed to resetting by the hour which is what happens in the query written above) so I have not been able to generalize your answer yet to solve the question I asked.

Comment: Can you update your sample which also includes that scenario?. The other way I think is to create your own table and populated based on your constraint per each name,hour and identifier but that will be out of the scope of the question.

Comment: I have added an additional table to include that scenario. Basically I show that over the course of 3 hours the publisher cap constraint does not reset, ONLY the hourly frequency cap resets.

Comment: Could you confirm if `identifier 2` and `identifier2` are the same? Also, on record `0` time is `2-28-2022 12:01 EST`?? Ok frequency is not allowed but then `no more than 2 rows Per name Per hourly block` is still true?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes: Identifier 2 = Identifier2, and record 0 should be 3/08 i just corrected the date:  "frequency cap" means that there is a bound on how frequently a name can appear in an hour. An "hourly frequency cap of 2" means: that each name can only appear AT MOST twice per hour. Of course this is "per hour" so over the course of the day the name can appear MANY times (unless there is a "daily" frequency cap limiting that which does not exist in our second table). In general one can define, minutely, hourly, daily, weekly yearly etc... caps

Comment: To clarify further when I wrote: "no more than 2 rows Per name Per hourly block" another of way saying that is "no more than 2 rows per name containing the same hour"

Comment: I have updated the code, please take a look.

Comment: Any updates? @frogeyedpeas??

Comment: Yes sir thank your for your dilgence! so this also gets tripped by the third table I have put up. The common thread I'm seeing is that the decision on whether or not to ACCEPT a row is a function of all the rows that have been accepted SO FAR, and none of the queries I received as answers yet seem to maintain that internal state which might be the crux of the issue. I hope there is a work around.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution-

```
WITH tab1 AS (
SELECT *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1) ORDER      BY time1) AS r_numt,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY time1) AS r_numi
FROM tablename
)
SELECT * FROM tab1
WHERE r_numt <=2
  AND  r_numi <= 2
ORDER BY time1;
```

The dataset-

```
Row name    time1                   identifier
--- ----    -----                   ----------
1   Sid     2022-02-28 15:55:00 UTC identifier1
2   Bob     2022-02-28 15:50:00 UTC identifier2
3   Sid     2022-02-28 15:45:00 UTC identifier2
4   Sid     2022-02-28 15:35:00 UTC identifier2
5   Bob     2022-02-28 15:25:00 UTC identifier1
```

And the results-

```
Row name    time1                   identifier
--- ----    -----                   ----------
1   Bob     2022-02-28 15:25:00 UTC identifier1
2   Sid     2022-02-28 15:35:00 UTC identifier2
3   Sid     2022-02-28 15:45:00 UTC identifier2
```

Solution for the additional details...

```
WITH tab2 AS (
WITH tab1 AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1) ORDER BY time1) AS r_numt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1), identifier ORDER BY time1) AS r_numi
  FROM `sada-gautam.dataset1.test_g12`

)

SELECT name, STRING(time1, "America/Los_Angeles"), identifier,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY time1) AS r_numii
FROM tab1
WHERE r_numt <=2
  AND  r_numi <= 2
ORDER BY time1

)
SELECT *
FROM tab2
where r_numii <= 2
;
```

The sample dataset is the same as you have mentioned in the question.

The results are matching with your expected output.

```
Row name    time1                   identifier
--- ----    -----                   ----------
1   Bob     2022-03-08 07:25:00-08  identifier1
2   Bob     2022-03-08 07:26:00-08  identifier3
3   Bob     2022-03-08 08:01:00-08  identifier2
4   Bob     2022-03-08 08:02:00-08  identifier2
```

**Update for the Third_Table requirements**

```
WITH tab2 AS (
WITH tab1 AS (
  SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1) ORDER BY time1) AS r_numt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, identifier, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1) ORDER BY time1) AS r_numi
  FROM `sada-gautam.dataset1.test_third_table`

)

SELECT name, STRING(time1, "America/Los_Angeles"), identifier,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY time1) AS r_numii
FROM tab1
WHERE r_numt <=2
  AND  r_numi <= 2
ORDER BY time1
```

)
SELECT *
FROM tab2
where r_numii <= 2
;

And the results running on the third table example dataset

```
Row name    time1                   identifier
--- ----    -----                   ----------
1   Sid     2022-02-28 07:00:00-08  identifier1
2   Sid     2022-02-28 07:01:00-08  identifier1
3   Bob     2022-02-28 07:04:00-08  identifier2
```

Please notice the only change in the new query is at line#4...

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, identifier, EXTRACT(HOUR FROM time1) ORDER BY time1) AS r_numi
```

Comment: Hi thank your for taking the time to write this, while this works on the first test example I gave it doesn't solve the problem as described. I have added a second table to make it clear why, the  r_numi <= 2 constraint in this case would cause us to drop rows (2,3) in the second table, while we want to keep those rows, since we are trying to satisfy the publisher cap, WHEN we can (i.e. not blocked by frequency cap first), on a first come first serve basis

Comment: On this line you can change the conditions in the where clause or change the partitions to meet other requirements. I will take a look at your updated constraint and will update on this post later today.

Comment: Ok this seems like it works, i'm just wrapping my head around it, and making sure no edge cases were missed

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work either. adding to my question to reveal why

Comment: I have added a third table to make it clear what the shortcomings of this are

Comment: Updated for the third table details.

Comment: hi it doesn't really capture the problem as stated, i have added a fourth table to make this clear why

Comment: Hi @SidharthGhoshal, with your fourth table it becomes clear that you need a 'procedural' language to handle this. The iteration over result set and updating the 'state' is the reason to go for something more than SQL. I saw your notes under 'Some methodologies I considered'. That is the right direction. In using BigQuery scripting (#2), I think you can resolve the - one query per row - situation. Also, you could consider options of using Dataflow (Java/Python).

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest a different approach to your problem. We use a procedure to do the inserts. The procedure checks the conditions in the WHERE clause. This is a fairly basic procedure with non local variables and only one statement. As you can see we call the procedure 12 times, but only 7 inserts are made.
NB I have created this using MSSQL Server setting. It will need to be adjusted for your bigQuery (which I do not have) but this gives you a working example to understand the principal.
NB `CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), scanTime, 120)` is to truncate the datetime to remove minutes and seconds.

> ```
> CREATE TABLE scans(
> name VARCHAR(10),
> scanTime DATETIME,
> identifier VARCHAR(25));
> GO
> ```

> ```
> CREATE PROCEDURE insertScans (
>    @name varchar(10),
>    @time datetime, 
>    @identifier varchar(25)) AS
> BEGIN
> INSERT  INTO scans 
> SELECT @name,@time,@identifier
>           WHERE (select count(*) from scans where identifier = @identifier) < 2
>        AND   
>           ( SELECT COUNT (*) FROM scans
>             WHERE @name = name
>             AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), scanTime, 120)
>             = CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), @time, 120) ) <2
> END
> ```

> ```
> EXEC insertScans 'Sid','20220228 10:55','identifier1';
> EXEC insertScans 'Bob','20220228 10:50','identifier2';
> EXEC insertScans 'Sid','20220228 10:55','identifier3';
> EXEC insertScans 'Bob','20220228 10:50','identifier3';
> EXEC insertScans 'Sid','20220228 10:55','identifier1';
> EXEC insertScans 'Bob','20220228 10:50','identifier2';
> EXEC insertScans 'Sid','20220228 10:45','identifier2';
> EXEC insertScans 'Jan','20220228 10:35','identifier2';
> EXEC insertScans 'Jan','20220228 10:25','identifier1';
> EXEC insertScans 'Sid','20220228 10:55','identifier3';
> EXEC insertScans 'Bob','20220228 11:50','identifier3';
> EXEC insertScans 'Bob','20220228 11:50','identifier4';
> SELECT name, scanTime, identifier FROM scans ORDER BY scanTime, name;
> ```

> ```
> name | scanTime                | identifier 
> :--- | :---------------------- | :----------
> Jan  | 2022-02-28 10:25:00.000 | identifier1
> Jan  | 2022-02-28 10:35:00.000 | identifier2
> Bob  | 2022-02-28 10:50:00.000 | identifier2
> Bob  | 2022-02-28 10:50:00.000 | identifier3
> Sid  | 2022-02-28 10:55:00.000 | identifier1
> Sid  | 2022-02-28 10:55:00.000 | identifier3
> Bob  | 2022-02-28 11:50:00.000 | identifier4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b7c28eed08e2eb4a91680152b8ca61df)*